# How to enforce a constraint violation when inserting non-integer number to integer column?

Tags: sql, oracle

As you can see from the example below I know how to enforce a range with a check constraint and how to enforce a column to contain only an integer.

What puzzles me is when inserting non-integer number Oracle doesn't raise constraint violation error but instead silently rounds the number to an integer.

How do I prevent insertion of non-integer number values ? Instead of the insertion I'd like to have a constraint violation.

In working on 11g but if the answer is different for 12c (and future releases) those answers are also welcome.

**Example:**

```
create table so59_t (
 id number(38)
,a number(38)
,constraint a_ch check (a > 0)
);

--
-- the following values raise a constraint violation as expected
--
SQL> insert into so59_t values(1, -1);
insert into so59_t values(1, -1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST.A_CH) violated

SQL> insert into so59_t values(2, 0);
insert into so59_t values(2, 0)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST.A_CH) violated

--    
-- the following values are silently rounded and successfully inserted
-- however I'd like to have a constraint violation instead
--
SQL> insert into so59_t values(3, 1.4);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into so59_t values(4, 1.5);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from so59_t;

        ID          A
---------- ----------
         3          1
         4          2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be in fact impossible. Let's study [the fine manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref118).

How an integer is specified:

> Specify an integer using the following form:
>
> `NUMBER(p)`
>
> This represents a fixed-point number with precision p and scale 0 and is equivalent to `NUMBER(p,0)`.

So here we've `precision = 38` and `scale = 0`. And the manual says following (*emphasis mine*):

> It is good practice to specify the scale and precision of a fixed-point number column for extra integrity checking on input. Specifying scale and precision does not force all values to a fixed length. *If a value exceeds the precision, then Oracle returns an error. If a value exceeds the scale, then Oracle rounds it.*

Based on the trials in this question the rounding takes place before constraints and triggers (not shown here but a print statement in before-insert-trigger printed the rounded value).

My conclusion at the moment is that there is no way to get an access to the non-rounded value. This is the "correct" answer until someone proves otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Create Check

```
constraint a_int check (a = ROUND(a))
```

EDIT: one should read the syntax diagram BEFORE posting...

EDIT: create the column as number(38,1) like sanjay radadiya suggested

Comment: Uh, can you provide a minimal working example please as I can't get this working ?

Comment: Did you test this before answering? I wouldn't expect this to work, I would expect the rounding to take place before the constraint gets checked, so that by the time `a = ROUND(a)` gets evaluated, it's true.

Comment: @hvd My test verifies your assumption. Seems that this constraint always evaluates to true.

Comment: Unfortunately the rounding doesn't go away with `number(38,1)`.

Comment: This is harder as on the first look. An ugly try could be to restrict insert/update access over a view with number(float?) instead of number(38), the check constraints and an instead of trigger. Don't have an Oracle 11 at hand, so i can't test it

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I have come to the conclusion this might be in fact impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression on constraint you can do validation for numeric number

```
create table so59_t (
  id number(38)
 ,a number
 ,constraint a_ch check (REGEXP_COUNT(a, '^[1-9]\d*$')<>0 and length(a)<=38)
);
```

Comment: Hi @user272735 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark

Comment: Hi, your idea was good, as i said, but thinking about it, 14,0003 would still get through, i think...

Comment: ohhhh i got it you are right ok i am trying to face this.

Comment: I'm not quite satisfied with this answer, thought it has some merit. First `number(38,1)` is not an integer. Second it doesn't cover all issues as some values (like 1.04) still leak in as the fundamental issue, rounding, doesn't go away. Third the regex is weird - I think it should be rewritten to `regexp_count(a, '^[[:digit:]]+$') = 1` instead. Anyway the regex brings no additional value compared to `round` suggested by @Turo here as the "magic" is essentially in column type definition `number(38,1)`.

Comment: @user272735 : i have edited my answer with some changes like number datatype with unlimited but give limit in check constraint.

Comment: @Turo: here you can try using 14.0003 or any other non-integer.

Comment: Sorry but do you test your answers at all ? I appreciate your effort but to me it unfortunately starts to look like you don't know what you're doing ...

Comment: It is always a bad idea to verify number expression by regex, there are too many exceptions, e.g. "1.0" is valid but would not pass. Also the length check is useless. '[1-9]\d' is also useless.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I have come to the conclusion this might be in fact impossible.